# Why doesn't Arch have grub prober enabled by default?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I used Endeavour OS and I have had to recently install a few other distros on the drive. However I realized that I couldn't just run `os-prober` to try detecting the other OS.

I wonder why is this the case where other distros like MXlinux (debian) and  fedora don't have this issue.

Why do I have to enable it in config only in Arch based distros?

Comment: Grub 2.06 now recommends that you not use os-prober or just run once. Some sort of security issue as it scans every partition for an operating system. Grub update is also a lot faster on my Ubuntu system with it off, as I have many partitions. I also have many old installs and do not want then in grub, so only add boot stanzas I want into 40_custom.

Answer (score 1):

In pure Arch the grub package and the os-prober package are two separate things. Therefore to set `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` would lead to an error if only grub is installed.

In Arch you make lots of decisions about what to install and what not to install. This is just one of those. If you only run Arch, you don’t need os-prober.

Comment: Many thanks indeed